# If $x = 3^{1/3} + 3^{2/3} + 3$, find the value of $x^3 - 9x^2 + 18x - 12$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, radicals

> If $x = 3^{1/3} + 3^{2/3} + 3$, find the value of $$x^3 - 9x^2 + 18x - 12.$$

This is not a homework problem. I'm not even a student. I'm going through an old textbook. I know this is a simple problem. Can't seem to crack it though.

Comment: This seems like an odd question for someone who isn't a student. May I ask what you are calculating this for?

Comment: @AlexSilva Expression or formula or function perhaps, but not an equation.

Comment: @JackM, you are right.

Comment: I'm going through an old textbook. I know this is a simple problem. Can't seem to crack it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense to let $y = x - 3 = 3^{1 \over 3} + 3^{2 \over 3}$. You are to compute
$$(y + 3)^3 -9(y + 3)^2 + 18(y + 3) - 12$$
This works out to 
$$y^3 - 9y - 12$$
Note that $y^3 = (3^{1 \over 3})^3(1 + 3^{1 \over 3})^3 = 3(1 + 3*3^{1 \over 3} + 3*3^{2 \over 3} + 3) = 3(4 + 3y) = 12 + 9y$. Thus $y^3 - 9y - 12 = 0$.

Answer (score 5):

Put $t=\sqrt[3]{3}$, so we have  $t^3=3.$ Then 
$$
x=t+t^2+t^3=t(1+t+t^2)=t \frac{t^3-1}{t-1}=\frac{2t}{t-1}.
$$
Now substitute this $x$ to ${x}^{3}-9\,{x}^{2}+18\,x-12$:
$$
{x}^{3}-9\,{x}^{2}+18\,x-12=8\,{\frac {{t}^{3}}{ \left( t-1 \right) ^{3}}}-36\,{\frac {{t}^{2}}{
 \left( t-1 \right) ^{2}}}+36\,{\frac {t}{t-1}}-12=\ldots=-4\,{\frac {{t}^{3}-3}{ \left( t-1 \right) ^{3}}}=0.
$$

Comment: Brilliant. t = 3^1/3 is the key.

Comment: @rishi_devan Well, $t=3^{1/3}$ was just a trick to make the formulae prettier and easier to deal with - you can do the exact same manipulations and come to the same answer by leaving $3^{1/3}$ as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: work directly by "foiling out" the products. While doing that use that two terms with the same base, raised to a power, mean add the exponents. Everything will then boil down to integers, or integers times $3^{1/3},$ or integers times $3^{2/3}.$ What I mean by foiling out is that, e.g., $x^2=(3^{1/3}+3^{2/3}+3)\cdot (3^{1/3}+3^{2/3}+3)$ for which each of the three terms in the first are to be multiplied by each of them in the second. Then simplify the resulting products by adding exponents as noted.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a simpler approach. This seems brute force, but I guess there isn't any other way.

Comment: @rishi_devan  There may be a simpler approach, but using more theory. I'll think about that...  Hmm: looks like Leox in his answer above has already made that work out fine!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\,a = \sqrt[3]3.\, $  $\, (\!\overbrace{x\!-\!3}^{\Large a^2+a}\!)^2 = \overbrace{a^4}^{\Large 3a}\!+\overbrace{2a^3}^{\Large 6}+a^2\,$

Therefore  $\ \color{#0a0}{x^2\!-6x\!+\!3\, =\, a^2\!+\!3a}.\ $ By very simple arithmetic we have:

$\begin{align}  f(x)\, & =\ (x-3)\,(\color{#0a0}{x^2\!-6x+3})\, -\, 3(x+1)\ \ {\rm\ via\ \ Division\ Algorithm}\\
 & = (a^2\!+\!a)\,\color{#0a0}{(a^2\!+\!3a)}\, -\, 3(a^2+a+4)\\
 &= \underbrace{a^4}_{\Large 3a}\!\!+\underbrace{4a^3}_{\Large\! 4\,\cdot\, 3}\!+3a^2\, -\, 3(a^2+a+4)\, =\, 0
\end{align}$